# pnpm create vite EACCES EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/path/to/.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-1723'

Tags: pnpm

```
pnpm create vite
 EACCES  EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/path/to/.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-1723'

pnpm: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/path/to/.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-1723'
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1405:3)
at Object.handler (/usr/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:210064:20)
at async /usr/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:219481:21
at async main (/usr/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:219448:34)
at async runPnpm (/usr/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:219704:5)
at async /usr/lib/node_modules/pnpm/dist/pnpm.cjs:219696:7
pnpm showing error
```

i tried copy and pasting lots of things i terminal. I don't know why but it needs `sudo` before it was not needed.